# Array is empty, shows nothing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, maatwebsite-excel

I tried to dd($inserts) but it shows me "[]". Here is my code in my controller.

```
public function importExcel()
{
    $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
    $inserts = [];
    Excel::load($path, function($reader) use ($inserts) {
        foreach ($reader->toArray() as $rows) { // <-- $rows pertains to array of rows
            foreach($rows as $row) { // <-- $row pertains to the row itself
                $inserts[] = ['title' => $row['title'], 'description' => $row['description']];
            }
        }    
    });
    dd($inserts);
    return back();
}
```

Comment: have you tried `$reader->toArray()` instead of `$reader->get()`?

Comment: error says "Trying to get property of non-object" @Wreigh

Comment: just replace `$reader->get()` with `$reader->toArray()`;

Comment: change row access from `$row->title` to `$row['title']` and so on.

Comment: Another error says "Undefined index: title" @Wreigh

Comment: last, try changing `as $row` to `as $key => $row`

Comment: Try dumping `$row` within the `foreach` with `dd($row)` and see what the `$row` element actually holds

Comment: Error still says Undefined index:title

Comment: array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "sadasd"
    "description" => "gwapo"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "adsad"
    "description" => "sdafa"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "sadasd"
    "description" => "fadfadf"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "da"
    "description" => "adfaf"
  ]
]
@devk thats the $row

Comment: I suggest that you read more about for loops and arrays in php. you have a nested array. therefore you need another for loop inside your current one.

Comment: Are you gonna help me out here? @Wreigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems you have "rows" instead of only a "row", you need to iterate through those rows again.

```
Excel::load($path, function($reader) use ($inserts) {
    foreach ($reader->toArray() as $rows) { // <-- $rows pertains to array of rows
        foreach($rows as $row) { // <-- $row pertains to the row itself
            $inserts[] = ['title' => $row['title'], 'description' => $row['description']];
        }
    }    
});
```

Actually you can just do this.

```
$rows = $reader->toArray();

foreach($rows as $row) { // <-- $row pertains to the row itself
    $inserts[] = ['title' => $row['title'], 'description' => $row['description']];
}
```

Or if you want to stick with `get` which I think returns a collection.

```
$rows = $reader->get();

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $inserts[] = ['title' => $row->title, 'description' => $row->description];
}
```

**UPDATE**

For the modification of `$inserts` array be reflected, you need to pass its reference.

```
function($reader) use (&$inserts) {
//                     ^-- add this to pass its reference.
```

Comment: You could actually just do `$inserts = Excel::load($path)->get()->first();`. No need for any additional loops since the database fields are the same as excel column names. But yeah what you posted should be correct.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion to dump, I wonder why I didn't have that in mind earlier.

Comment: Can i ask something? I tried to do like what you did but the $inserts has nothing inside when i tried to dd($inserts)

Comment: what does `Excel::load($path)->get()` look like if you `dd` it?

Comment: I judged by [that](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/docs/2.1/import/results#docs) and what the `$row` looked like. Maybe you need to remove the `->first()`. Or maybe you need to specify a closure, even if it does nothing.

Comment: I only dd($inserts) and it only looks like this "[]" @Wreigh

Comment: Are you still there sir?@Wreigh

Comment: @devk has already answered your question. update your question to reflect your current code, maybe insert the updated code at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @Wreigh i am not able to chat because the requirement should be more than 20 reputation

Comment: Yes but theres an error saying "Undefined index:title" @Wreigh

Comment: please try to `dd($rows)` in my second suggestion, so I can see what your data looks like.,

Comment: I can't dd($rows) outside the foreach so i only dd($rows) inside the first foreach and it shows like these: 
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "sadasd"
    "description" => "gwapo"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "adsad"
    "description" => "sdafa"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "sadasd"
    "description" => "fadfadf"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "da"
    "description" => "adfaf"
  ]
]

Comment: hi, modification of `$inserts` inside the closure is not being reflected after the closure has been called. wait, I'm investigating

Comment: question, why can't you `dd($rows)` outside foreach?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOUR'E THE BEST @Wreigh